# Problem with delete[], how to partially delete the memory?

Tags: c++

When we learn dynamic allocation in c++, the simplest example about delete[] is :

```
int main()
{
    size_t n = 5;
    int *p = new int[n];
    delete[] p;
}
```

In plain English `delete[]` is able to delete an C-like array from the heap memory which is previously allocated by the `new`. However, i'm getting errors for the following code.

```
int main()
{
    size_t n = 5;
    int *p = new int[n];
    p++;         //move the pointer to the second element of the array
    delete[] p;
}
```

I was thinking if this could delete the same heap memory, but from the second element onwards. however, i'm getting some error which i dont understand:

```
Test Prep(51600,0x1000d1dc0) malloc: *** error for object 0x100537134: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

Comment: No, that's not how this works. You have to delete the exact pointer you got from `new` (and since you modified it with `p++` it's not the same pointer anymore). You can't delete just some of it, it's all or nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's simply [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) to `delete` a pointer that's *not* allocated by `new`. *Undefined behaviour* doesn't necessarily give any errors!

You're changing the pointer to point to the next element - which isn't what  `new` returned.

There's no way to *partially* delete as you wanted. You should look at containers such as [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which supports (and manages the allocations) such partial deletion/resizing.

Comment: holy sh*t, I just learned, that `std::vector::shrink_to_fit` may reallocate. I always thought it would just shorten the allocated by some magic.