# Problem in Deleting the elements of an array allocated with new[]

Tags: c++, c++11, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

This question is similar to [Problem with delete[], how to partially delete the memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58971779/problem-with-delete-how-to-partially-delete-the-memory)

I understand that deleting an array after incrementing its pointer is not possible as it loses the track of how many bytes to clean. But, I am not able to understand why one-by-one delete/deallocation of a dynamic array doesn't work either.

```
int main()
{
    int n = 5;
    int *p = new int[n];
 
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
        delete &p[i];
    }
}
```

I believe this should work, but in clang 12.0 it fails with the invalid pointer error. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Do you know what `delete` does and how `delete`-ing something is different from remoing an element from an array? It's a false assumption that `delete` could be used to remove elements from arrays.

Comment: Does the answer on the question you link not answer your question? "It's simply undefined behaviour to delete a pointer that's not allocated by new." There you go. You cannot `delete` what has been allocated via `new[]`

Comment: Please just use `std::array` and/or `std::vector` exclusively already.

Comment: `int *p = new int[n];` can be deleted in one call with `delete [] p;`

Comment: "I understand that deleting an array after incrementing its pointer is not possibl" well it is possible. You can always restore the original pointer. `int* p = new int[42]; ++p; --p; delete [] p;` no problem with that

Comment: Meta answer: Ever since [C++11 smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), using `new` in code is basically a design flaw. Using `new` outside e.g. a constructor (with the appropriate `delete` in the destructor) was *always* a design flaw.

Comment: "One-by-one" doesn't work because you cannot `delete` things which you did not `new`, and the code did not `new` those things one-by-one.

Comment: Why? Because the c++ standard says so :)

Answer (score 1):

You allocated one object of the type `int[n]` (one extent of memory for an array) using the operator new

```
int *p = new int[n];
```

Elements of the array were not allocated dynamically separately.

So to delete it you just need to write

```
delete []p;
```

If for example you allocated an array of pointers like

```
int **p = new int *[n];
```

and then for each pointer of the array you allocated an object of the type int like

```
for ( int i = 0;i < n;++i ) 
{
    p[i] = new int( i );
}
```

then to delete all the allocated objects you need to write

```
for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
{
    delete p[i];
}
delete []p;
```

That is the number of calling of the operator delete or delete [] one to one corresponds to the number of calling operator new or new [].

Answer (score 1):

An array is a contiguous object in memory of a specific size. It is *one* object where you can place your data in and therefore you can only free/delete it as *one* object.

You are thinking that an array is a list of multiple objects, but that's not true. That would be true for something like a linked list, where you allocate individual objects and link them together.

Comment: *'one object'* is problematic wording – maybe correct from point of view of the operating system/memory management – but objects in C++ are something different. With arrays, multiple C++ objects can reside in one single memory 'object'…

Comment: @Aconcagua agreed. Do you have a suggestion? Unfortunately the standards document also uses the overloaded word "object". Per [intro.object] the array is an object and the array elements are considered sub-objects. Maybe we stick to that term and with your clarifying comment, it should be understandable.

Comment: Hm... That relationship of array as object and array elements as subobjects might be elaborated a bit more explicit – and perhaps compared to normal class/struct objects, where as well there cannot be deleted one single member from...

Answer (score 1):

One `new` always goes with one `delete`. Just as that.

In detail, when we request an array using `new`, what we actually do is to get a pointer that controls a **contiguous & fixed** block on the memory. Whatever we do with that array, we do it through that pointer and this pointer associates strictly with the array itself.

Furthermore, let's assume that you were able to `delete` an elemnent in the middle of that array. After the deletion, that array would fall apart and they are not contiguous anymore! By then, an array would not really be an array!

Because of that, we can not 'chop off' an array into separate pieces. We must always treat an array as one thing, not distinctive elements scattered around the memory.

Answer (score 0):

Greatly simplyfyinh: in most systems memory is allocated in logical blocks which are described by the starting pointer of the allocated block.

So if you allocate an array:

```
int* array = new int[100];
```

OS stores the information of that allocation as a pair (simplifying) (block_begin, size) -> (value of array ptr, 100)

Thus when you deallocate the memory you don't need to specify how much memory you allocated i.e:

```
// you use
delete[] array; // won't go into detail why you do delete[] instead of delete - mostly it is due to C++ way of handling destruction of objects
// instead of
delete[100] array;
```

In fact in bare C you would do this with:

```
int* array = malloc(100 * sizeof(int))
[...]
free(array)
```

So in most OS'es it is not possible due to the way they are implemented.

However theoretically allocating large chunk of memory in fact allocate many smaller blocks which *could* be deallocated this way, but still it would deallocate smaller blocks at a time **not** one-by-one.

Answer (score 0):

All of `new` or `new[]` and even C's `malloc` do exactly the same in respect to memory: requesting a fix block of memory from the operating system.

You cannot split up this block of memory and return it partially to the operating system, that's simply not supported, thus you cannot `delete` a single element from the array either. Only all or none…

If you need to remove an element from an array all you can do is copy the subsequent elements one position towards front, overwriting the element to delete and additionally remember how many elements actually are valid – the elements at the end of the array stay alive!

If these need to be destructed immediately you might call the destructor explicitly – and then assure that it isn't called again on an already destructed element when `delete[]`ing the array (otherwise undefined behaviour!) – ending in not calling `new[]` and `delete[]` at all but instead `malloc`, placement `new` for each element, `std::launder` any pointer to any element created that way and finally explicitly calling the constructor when needed.

Sounds like much of a hassle, doesn't it? Well, there's `std::vector` doing all this stuff for you! You should this one it instead…

Side note: You could get similar behaviour if you use an array of pointers; you then can – and need to – maintain (i.e. control its lifetime) each object individually. Further disadvantages are an additional level of pointer indirection whenever you access the array members and the array members indeed being scattered around the memory (though this can turn into an advantage if you need to move objects around your array and copying/moving objects is expensive – still you would to prefer a `std::vector`, of pointers this time, though; insertions, deletions and managing the pointer array itself, among others, get much safer and much less complicated).